# Delay type inference?

Tags: scala

Given that the following does not compile

```
trait Wrapper[T]{
    def apply[U](f: U) = f(this)
}
trait Mapper{
    def apply[V](w: Wrapper[V]): Option[V]
}
```

How could we write `Wrapper.apply` so that such an instance can accept a `Mapper` instance?

The problem is that I cannot constrain `U` correctly because the used function (`Mapper.apply`) is itself generic.

I also cannot “promote” the input/output types of the `Mapper.apply` to type members as the function is generic.

Answer (score 1):

> How could we write Wrapper.apply so that such an instance can accept a Mapper instance?

Well, `def apply(f: Mapper) = f(this)`?

Or

```
trait Wrapper[T]{
    def apply[U](f: Wrapper[T] => U) = f(this)
}

val wrapper: Wrapper[Int] = ...
val mapper: Mapper = ...
wrapper.apply(mapper(_))
```

though this doesn't really accept the `Mapper` instance directly.

Of course, you can have both `Mapper`-taking and function-taking methods as overloads.

Comment: yes, I guess I missed the most important part, I would like to subclass the Mapper with different constraints, like IntMapper{def apply[V <: Int](w : Wrapper[V]) : Option[V]} and force the compiler to throw a type error for (w : Wrapper[String])(m : IntMapper)

Comment: `IntMapper` can't be a subtype of `Mapper` as you wrote it. You could e.g. make the constraint a type parameter of `Mapper` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
trait Wrapper[T]{
  final def apply[U >: T](m: Mapper[U]): Option[T] = m(this)
}

trait Mapper[-T] {
  def apply[V <: T](w: Wrapper[V]): Option[V]
}
```

If you can share an example use case, I could be sure if this is what you need.